# I only encrypt saved game data in plist using AES256. Do I have to check US Export?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I use RNEncryptor to encrypt the saved data of the game in .plist using AES256

Do I have to check yes to Export Compliance??

because I am having difficulties in obtaining the CIN

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you need to take proper legal advice on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will have to check the using encryption box, you are using encryption.